# Authorize filters vs Action Filters

Tags: .net, action-filter, authorize-attribute

i m using .NET mvc2 for my application. I want some custom authorization on my actions. I have googled a bit and there seems to be two options available.

- Implement logic in onActionExecuting in custom Action Filter, [see this post](http://blog.wekeroad.com/blog/aspnet-mvc-securing-your-controller-actions/)
- Subclass authorizeattribute or implement Iauthorization interface and put my logic there

My question here is that which technique is preferable with pros and cons of using each technique

edited: Moreover I can override onActionExecuting and onAuthorization in my base controller that gives me benefit of accessing controller variables directly.

Comment: Did you find any pro and cons?
Right now i am dealing with the same question.

What was your solution?

Comment: using onActionExecuting gives u benefit of accessing private members as well. while in filters u probably have access to only public properties and methods. i used subclass of AuthorizeAttribute because this is what it is for and gives u clean separation of concerns

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While both options are OK, it is best to subclass AuthorizeAttribute for these reasons:

1. Separation of concerns.
2. MVC provides the AuthorizeAttribute for this purpose (don't fight the framework).
3. The authorization filter is run first -- before other filters (per Pro ASP.NET MVC3 Framework, page 431).  This ensures no unnecessary code will execute if an unauthorized user hits your controller/action.